# MCMC problem for Acoustic Scale Cosmology

Tags: numerical-integration, physics, markov-chains

I'm using this MCMC Mathematica package https://github.com/joshburkart/mathematica-mcmc to do a MCMC on number of different data sets for a problem. I'm almost done but I have one problem. Whenever I try to do the MCMC for the $\pi\cdot r(z*)/(r_s(z*))$ I get an error. The formula can be seen in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1613v1.pdf right above equation 31 and is labeled under $l_a$. I'm at wits end to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have

```
CMB111[M_?NumberQ, w_?NumberQ, W_?NumberQ, h_?NumberQ, Z_?NumberQ] := 
 Sqrt[3]*Pi*
  NIntegrate[
   1/(\[Sqrt](1/
        2 (2 + z (6 - 6 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) w - 
             3 (-5 + 0.00025041348576`/h^2 + 5 M) w z - 
             9 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) w^2 z + 
             z (6 - 3 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) W + 
                2 z (M + (0.000041735580959999996` (4 + z))/
                   h^2)))))), {z, 0, Z}]
```

as my $\pi\cdot r(z*)$ and

```
CMB33[M_?NumberQ, w_?NumberQ, W_?NumberQ, h_?NumberQ, Z_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(1/
     Sqrt[1/2 (2 + 
         Z (6 - 6 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) w - 
            3 (-5 + 0.00025041348576`/h^2 + 5 M) w *Z - 
            9 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) w^2 *Z + 
            Z (6 - 3 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) W + 
               2 *Z (M + (0.000041735580959999996` (4 + Z))/
                  h^2))))])*(1/
     Sqrt[1 + ((3*2.258*10^-2)/(4*2.469*10^-5))*(1 + z)]), {z, Z, 
   10^6}]
```

as my $r_s(z*)$ term. When I evaluate

```
MCMC[(-1/2)*(302.09 - 
 CMB111[M, W, w, h, 1091.3]/
  CMB33[M, W, w, h, 1091.3])^2, {{M, .28, .001, Real}, {w, -1, .001, Real}, {W, 0, .001, Real}, {h, .7, .001, Real}, {m, .135, .001, Real}}, 39000]
```

Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

Can anyone offer any pointers. Am I missing something with my definition of acoustic scale. Do I need to something else rather then just run this native MCMC package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message displayed during the evaluation of these expressions by NIntegrate can be eliminated through the convenient choice of another integration strategy. Looking at the ArXiV paper its a little hard to find the above expressions in order to say if they are correct or not. The integral can be calculated using the LocalAdaptive strategy, by which we recursively partitionate the integration domain into subregions and reduce the estimated errors.

```
CMB111[M_?NumberQ, w_?NumberQ, W_?NumberQ, h_?NumberQ, Z_?NumberQ] :=

 Sqrt[3]*Pi*
  NIntegrate[
   1/(\[Sqrt](1/
         2 (2 + z (6 - 6 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) w - 
             3 (-5 + 0.00025041348576`/h^2 + 5 M) w z - 
             9 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) w^2 z + 
             z (6 - 3 (-1 + 0.000041735580959999996`/h^2 + M) W + 
                2 z (M + (0.000041735580959999996` (4 + z))/
                    h^2)))))), {z, 0, Z}
   , Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule", 
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, MaxRecursion -> 200, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10
   ]
```

Also, by adopting the ClenshawCurtisRule rule the integration time can be reduced. The final output is

> "MCMCResult"[{M -> -0.0281647, w -> -0.799217, W -> 0.87625,    h ->
>   1.58387,    m -> 0.149589}, "39000"]

The convergence rate can be tuned depending on your required goals and final precision. The WorkingPrecision of this kernel is no larger than 17 algarisms, as you can verify increasing this option.

Comment: Thank you very much your help is greatly appreciated.